# CKEditor toolbar not visible in inline editing

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, inline-editing

I want to use a floating toolbar and inline editing.
But by default, the Toolbar is not visible.
The inline editing works pretty fine!

I didn't found any helpful hints and understood it like: The Toolbar should be there by default.

Answer (score 0):

> The Toolbar should be there by default.

Yes, the toolbar should be there by default.

Please have a look at this [page](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/17-08-11-06-04/full/samples/old) and check out all three inline samples. As you can see, the editor works there without problems. In your editor instance you can navigate to the `ckeditor/samples/old` folder to check out the code and make sure you have initialized the editor in the same way.

You can also open the browser's developer tools Console Tab and Net Tab and see if you are getting any JavaScript errors or HTTP errors like 404.

Finally, please make sure the styles used on your page don't conflict with the editor toolbar and that the toolbar works but e.g. shows outside of viewport.